# array becomes null in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: xcode, arrays, json, ios5

I am parsing a json file and then trying to pass an array to cellForRowAtIndexPath but the array becomes null.
  in .h

```
@interface NewsControllor : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *latestNews;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *sortedArray;
@end
```

in .m

```
@synthesize latestNews;
@synthesize sortedArray;
```

view will appear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                    NewsFeed];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

}

fetched data

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {


//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions 
                      error:&error];

self.latestNews = [json objectForKey:@"News"]; //2

//sort the json array
NSSortDescriptor *latestnewssorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortNumber" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:latestnewssorter,nil];
self.sortedArray =[latestNews sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:     (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSLog(@"News: %@", self.latestNews);    

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsCell"];

NSDictionary* item = [self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:0];   //[indexPath row]
cell.textLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"titleOfNews"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item objectForKey:@"detailOfNews"];
return cell;



}
```

i am testing that is why i am only returning 1 cell. my number of rows in section is also 1

Answer (score 0):

First try to log the description look for data:

```
NSLog(@"NSData description: %@", [data description]);
```

If it logs some valid hex data, then you are receiving data from specified URL.
Else, there is something wrong with your `NSURLConection`.

Comment: i did a log output in (fetchedData) and a array does print out. but if i put the log printout in cellForRowAtIndexPath the array comes back null.  so i can get my data source and sort it but it turns null in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: i put retain in the property and i am still getting null. i did find out it is something with the thread, but i thought nsarray's are thread safe. when i go back to main thread and print out log the array is null